# Select: Limit number of selected options

Tags: select, antd

I'm using [ANT Design's Select component](https://ant.design/components/select/) in multiple select mode. After two options are selected (see screenshot) I'd like to prevent any more from being selected. The field should not be disabled, so that you can deselect an option and select another.

I've tried the `onFocus` event, but it doesn't provide an event that I could use to `preventDefault` or otherwise keep from opening the dropdown. I've also tried adding a ref and calling `blur()` whenever the `onFocus` event is called. This closes the dropdown, but it's still visible for a second.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

If 3 or more options selected then with a simple condition you can disable other options.

Store selected options in state and while displaying options disable them based on condition.

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-leftpad-lu84g

Sample code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Select } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

const opts = ["a11", "b12", "c13", "d14", "e15"];

const Selectmultiple = () => {
  const [optionsSelected, setOptionsSelected] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = value => {
    console.log(`selected ${value}`);
    setOptionsSelected(value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        mode="multiple"
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        placeholder="Please select"
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        {opts.map(item => (
          <Option
            disabled={
              optionsSelected.length > 1
                ? optionsSelected.includes(item)
                  ? false
                  : true
                : false
            }
            key={item}
          >
            {item}
          </Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem using "open" prop:

```
const isMaxValues = value.length === limit;

<Select
   mode="multiple"
   disabled={false}
   {...(isMaxValues && { open: false, onDropdownVisibleChange: handleShowError })}
>
   {renderOptions()}
</Select>
```

So you still able to remove/deselect some options

Also you can provide isMaxValues option to renderOptions method and disable Options to be selected(if you need dropdown to be visible)